# How do I get Minecraft for Linux?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux

So I looked on the internet and found instructions for installing Minecraft for Linux. I downloaded OpenJDK 7 from the software center, and got Minecraft from the official site. I checked "allow executing file as a program" under permissions in properties. I went to "Open with..." but I can't seem to find "OpenJDK 7".

I am completely clueless by now, and I am not sure what to do. I may be doing something wrong, or is there something I am missing?

Comment: What happens when you typa java in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes you have to set permissions manually first via terminal - i don't know if the checkbox is enough. Execute the following command in the terminal:

```
chmod a+x path/to/minecraft/minecraft.jar
```

To start the game via console, execute:

```
java -jar path/to/minecraft/minecraft.jar
```

If that doesn't work, your JRE installation is invalid.

Comment: @Y U NO WORK Terminal says: "chmod: cannot access ‘path/to/minecraft/minecraft.jar’: No such file or directory<<"

Comment: ... you're, you're supposed to replace that with the actual path to minecraft.jar

Comment: @JohnHickox Well ... i thought it's obvious that you have to enter your OWN path there, I'd be surprised if that is your actually mc path.^^

Comment: says same thing

Comment: Then you're entering the path wrong or the file does not exist because you didn't download it yet or something. But this is not a problem with Java for sure then.^^

Comment: (no offense) please consider a basic linux course first

Comment: @Y U NO WORK Could you tell me where I can put it and what the path would be called, so that I know i'm not messing anything up?

Comment: @JohnHickox I have no idea how your directories look like. Usually you just have to put it anywhere, start it and then it downloads the actual minecraft into the `roaming` folder. I don't really see your problem here.

Comment: Never mind. I FINNALY FIGURED OUT WHAT WAS WRONG. For some reason, when choosing which program to open minecraft with, Open JDK 7 wouldn't show. I got Java 6, and it worked fine.